# I need this ansible task but done better

Tags: ansible, task

I have this Ansible tasks file which executes one of the 5 options based on the variable `harbor_patch__vm_region`. I'd like to implement the exact same behavior refactoring the code into (maybe) one line or in the least lines possible.

Seeing the same lines repeated 5 times just for the conditional variable does not seem correct to me. Is there a better way to do it?

```yaml
# file: harbor-patch/tasks/modify-scripts.yml
---
- name: "{{ __tpfx }}modify-scripts | Modify the scripts to use the Boadilla satellite"
  lineinfile: 
    path: '{{ harbor_patch__dest_directory }}/set_patch_env.sh'
    line: SAT=AAA.111.222.333.com
  when: harbor_patch__vm_region == "bo" or harbor_patch__vm_region == "az"

# CAN
- name: "{{ __tpfx }}modify-scripts | Modify the scripts to use the Cantabria satellite"
  lineinfile: 
    path: '{{ harbor_patch__dest_directory }}/set_patch_env.sh'
    line: SAT=BBB.111.222.333.com
  when: harbor_patch__vm_region == "cn" 

# MX
- name: "{{ __tpfx }}modify-scripts | Modify the scripts to use the Mexico satellite"
  lineinfile:   
    path: '{{ harbor_patch__dest_directory }}/set_patch_env.sh'
    line: SAT=CCC.111.222.333.com
  when: harbor_patch__vm_region == "mx"

# CHI
- name: "{{ __tpfx }}modify-scripts | Modify the scripts to use the Chile satellite"
  lineinfile: 
    path: '{{ harbor_patch__dest_directory }}/set_patch_env.sh'
    line: SAT=DDD.111.222.333.com
  when: harbor_patch__vm_region == "cl"

# UK
- name: "{{ __tpfx }}modify-scripts | Modify the scripts to use the UK satellite"
  lineinfile: 
    path: '{{ harbor_patch__dest_directory }}/set_patch_env.sh'
    line: SAT=EEE.111.222.333.com
  when: harbor_patch__vm_region == "uk"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a dict for your data somewhere in your vars:

```yaml
my_sats:
  az: AAA.111.222.333.com
  bo: AAA.111.222.333.com
  cn: BBB.111.222.333.com
  mx: CCC.111.222.333.com
  cl: DDD.111.222.333.com
  uk: EEE.111.222.333.com
```

Then add the line with the correct value:

```yaml
- name: "{{ __tpfx }}modify-scripts | Modify the scripts to use the correct satellite"
  lineinfile:   
    path: '{{ harbor_patch__dest_directory }}/set_patch_env.sh'
    line: "SAT={{ my_sats[harbor_patch__vm_region] | d('') }}"
  when: my_sats[harbor_patch__vm_region] is defined
```

The default value is just to avoid a possible ansible error when you hit an undefined region and will never be inserted since the when clause checks exactly for that.

Note that the above will not replace the line in your script if you change the region between two runs. If this is what you want to achieve, you need to modify your task:

```yaml
- name: "{{ __tpfx }}modify-scripts | Modify the scripts to use the correct satellite"
  lineinfile:   
    path: '{{ harbor_patch__dest_directory }}/set_patch_env.sh'
    regexp: "^SAT=.*$"
    line: "SAT={{ my_sats[harbor_patch__vm_region] | d('') }}"
  when: my_sats[harbor_patch__vm_region] is defined
```

Still, this will not change anything if you hit an undefined region. If you want to remove the line in case the region is unknown, you need to add a second task.

```yaml
- name: "{{ __tpfx }}modify-scripts | Remove SAT for unknown regions"
  lineinfile:   
    path: '{{ harbor_patch__dest_directory }}/set_patch_env.sh'
    regexp: "^SAT=.*$"
    state: absent
  when: my_sats[harbor_patch__vm_region] is not defined
```